# SimpleITK N4BiasFieldCorrection, not working with any data type

Tags: python

Just installed the latest version of SimpleITK and I'm trying to run a simple code as:

```
im = sitk.ReadImage('img.nii.gz')
im_bin = sitk.ReadImage('img_bin.nii.gz')
im_bfc = sitk.N4BiasFieldCorrection(im, im_bin)
```

the error is

```
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK N4BiasFieldCorrection: /scratch/dashboards/SimpleITK-OSX10.7-intel-pkg/SimpleITK/Code/Common/include/sitkDualMemberFunctionFactory.hxx:214:
sitk::ERROR: Pixel type: 64-bit signed integer is not supported in 2D byN3itk6simple32N4BiasFieldCorrectionImageFilterE
```

I tried with casting to different type, int, float, signed, unsigned, and I tried with 2d and 3d images. I tried as well to use https://itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen07/html/N4BiasFieldCorrection_8py-example.html 
And the error has always been the same. Other modules of SimpleITK appears to work. 
Any idea? Can you reproduce the error?
Thanks!

Comment: Same error with blank images of any type and dimension, as image = sitk.Image(256, 128, 64, sitk.sitkInt16)
image_bfc = sitk.N4BiasFieldCorrection(image, image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the real problem here. The "mask" here needs to be 8-bit or binary. So, you can use the `BinaryThreshold` filter of sitk for getting the mask, if the background can be thresholded out.

Comment: I would *love* to know how you actually got this to work, but this answer really doesn't contain enough information for anyone else to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way that I was able to get this working:

```
img = sitk.ReadImage(in_file)
img_mask = sitk.OtsuThreshold(img)
img = sitk.Cast(img, sitk.sitkFloat32)
corrector = sitk.N4BiasFieldCorrectionImageFilter()
img_c = corrector.Execute(img, img_mask)
```

Answer (score 0):

In answering my question, I found that the errors raised do not seem to be related to the real cause. If the mask is made with a threshold with sitk as

```
bth = sitk.BinaryThresholdImageFilter()
img_bin = bth.Execute(img)  
img_bin = -1 * (img_mask - 1)

im_bfc = sitk.N4BiasFieldCorrection(im, img_bin)
```

The algorithm works and no error is raised.
- will update if I find the real cause of the problem!

Comment: I am using the BRATS dataset, which has .mha files for MRI. Your solution didn't solve my problem, which is actually similar to your original one.